# Kotlin: Show AlertDialog when RecycleView item clicked

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

Now I'm studying to show AlertDialog when RecyclerView item clicked.
However, I don't know how to set the adapter for click listener.
Could you give me a tip?

Firstly, I tried to put the AlertDialog in this Main Activity.
Is this right position?

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val foodList = listOf(
        FoodModel("Noodle", 2),
        FoodModel("Cake", 3),
        FoodModel("Pizza", 4),
        FoodModel("Stake", 5),
        FoodModel("Chicken", 4)
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val adapter = FoodDataAdapter(foodList)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        foodListView.adapter = adapter
        foodListView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        fun onItemClick(item: FoodModel, position: Int) {
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            dialog.setTitle("Item deletion")
            dialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete this item?")
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            })
            dialog.setNegativeButton("No", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            })
            dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            })
            dialog.show()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Adapter.

```
class FoodDataAdapter(val list: List<FoodModel>):RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodDataViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FoodDataViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_food,parent,false)
        return FoodDataViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return list.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FoodDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.containerView.nameText.text=list[position].name
        holder.containerView.priceText.text="${list[position].price}dollar"
    }
}
```

View holder

```
class FoodDataViewHolder(override val containerView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),LayoutContainer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your code. MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FoodDataAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

var foodList = ArrayList<FoodModel>()
lateinit var adapter : FoodDataAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    foodlist.add(FoodModel("Noodle", 2))
    foodlist.add(FoodModel("Cake", 3))
    foodlist.add(FoodModel("Pizza", 4))
    foodlist.add(FoodModel("Stake", 5))
    foodlist.add(FoodModel("Chicken", 4))

    adapter = FoodDataAdapter(foodList, this)
    foodListView.adapter = adapter
    foodListView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

}

override fun alertDialog(position: Int) {
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    dialog.setTitle("Item deletion")
    dialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete this item?")
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ -> 
    adapter.removeItem(position)
    })
    dialog.setNegativeButton("No", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
    })
    dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
    })
    dialog.show()
}
}
```

FoodDataAdapter:

```
class FoodDataAdapter(var list: ArrayList<FoodModel>, var listener : FoodDataAdapter.OnItemClickListener):RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodDataAdapter.FoodDataViewHolder>(){

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun alertDialog(position : Int)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FoodDataViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_food,parent,false)
    return FoodDataViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.count()
}

fun removeItem(position: Int) {
    list.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FoodDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.nameText.text=list[position].name
    holder.priceText.text="${list[position].price}dollar"
}

inner class FoodDataViewHolder(containerView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),
    View.OnClickListener {

    var nameText: TextView = containerView.findViewById(R.id.nameText)
    var priceText: TextView = containerView.findViewById(R.id.priceText)

    init {
        containerView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        listener.alertDialog(adapterPosition)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: However, can I ask one more thing? how can I delete the selected list when I click the "Yes" button in the AlertDialog?

Comment: hmm..I got two errors. one is from the `list.remove(position)` in FoodDataAdapter. the message  is "Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch. And the second error is in Main Acticity, which is `var adapter: FoodDataAdapter = null`. Message is "Null can not be a value of a non-null type FoodDataAdapter"

Comment: list.removeAt(position), lateinit var adapter: FoodDataAdapter

Comment: It still remains the error, 'Unsolved reference'. I think we need to declare the `removeAt'. How do you think?

Comment: I I thought , you used arraylist. Change your list to ArrayList. Then it works

Comment: Thanks mate! but still have problems.. And also got another problem. I just added the question, below.

Answer (score 0):

I just put a declare code for 'removeAt' at the end of the Adapter like this,

```
class FoodDataAdapter(val list: List<FoodModel>,var itemClicklistener : OnItemClickListener):RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodDataAdapter.FoodDataViewHolder>() {

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FoodDataViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_food, parent, false)
        return FoodDataViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.count()
    }

    fun removeItem(position: Int) {
        list.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FoodDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.nameText.text = list[position].name
        holder.priceText.text = "${list[position].price} dollar"
    }

    inner class FoodDataViewHolder(containerView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        var nameText: TextView = containerView.findViewById(R.id.nameText)
        var priceText: TextView = containerView.findViewById(R.id.priceText)

        init {
            containerView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            itemClicklistener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}

private fun Any.removeAt(position: Int) {

}
```

and also changed the Main activity like this.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FoodDataAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private val foodList = arrayListOf(
        FoodModel("Noodle", 3),
        FoodModel("Cake", 5),
        FoodModel("Pizza", 7),
        FoodModel("Stake", 8),
        FoodModel("Chicken", 8)
    )
    var adapter: FoodDataAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        adapter = FoodDataAdapter(foodList, this)
        foodListView.adapter = adapter
        foodListView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        dialog.setTitle("Item deletion")
        dialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete this item?")
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            adapter?.removeItem(position)
        })
        dialog.setNegativeButton("No", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
        })
        dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
        })
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

And it works! but...one problem is..
after deletion of the list, the last list keep comes up.
the total number of list was not decreased..

[image]
[image]

lol
another 'Chicken' comes up..do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Convert your list to arrayList like my answer. And remove line Any.removeAt(position: Int)